# Cannot bind a list as content of expander

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, binding

Here is my Subject.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ListBoxBinding.Models
{
    public class Subject
    {
        private string name;
        public String Name
        {
            get{
                return name;
            }
            set{
                name=value;
            }
        }
        private string faculty;
        public string Faculty
        {
            get{
                return faculty;
            }
            set{
                faculty=value;
            }
        }
        private int hours;
        public int Hours
        {
            get
            {
                return hours;
            }
            set
            {
                hours = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Student.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ListBoxBinding.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        private string name;
        public String Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                name = value;
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Subject> Subjects = new ObservableCollection<Subject>();
    }
}
```

Here is my MyList.xaml. Pls help me what should i write in expander.content so that i can get the list of faculty of the subjects, the student is associated with as conent of the expander. I wrote a line which is not working.

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit" x:Class="ListBoxBinding.Views.MyList"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="MyItemsControl">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <toolkit:Expander HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Width="150" Header="{Binding Name}">
                        <toolkit:Expander.Content>
                            <!-- Help needed here -- what should i write here? -->
                            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding subjects}" DisplayMemberPath="Faculty"/>
                        </toolkit:Expander.Content>
                    </toolkit:Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        </ItemsControl>


    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is my MyList.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using ListBoxBinding.Models;
namespace ListBoxBinding.Views
{
    public partial class MyList : UserControl
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Student> students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();

        public void SetData()
        {
            for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
            {
                Student s = new Student();
                s.Name="Student "+i.ToString();
                students.Add(s);
            }
            foreach(Student s in students)
            {
                for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
                {
                    Subject sj = new Subject();
                    sj.Name="subject "+i;
                    sj.Faculty = "faculty"+i;
                    sj.Hours = i+10;
                    s.Subjects.Add(sj);
                }
            }
        }
        public MyList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetData();
            MyItemsControl.ItemsSource = students;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, Please point me to a resource with the help of which I can master these tricky concepts of binding. Please excuse me for the long post (most of which is useless, but posted for clarity purpose)

Here is the output I am getting :([image: The output is missing faculty names]

Comment: use [snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to see if there is a binding error and the controls set DataContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first glance I see that you bind to subjects as this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding subjects}"
```

There is no property named `subjects` in your model and `Subjects` is a field so it will not work. You have to have a property with exact (case sensitive) name as in binding for it to work.

As for your future progress look at INotifyPropertyChanged interface and its role in binding.

Answer (score 0):

In your example Binding paths are wrong. First you should set ItemsControl source as Students. Then, for inner ListBox you should set its ItemsSource for Subjects. Please be sure that your collection is a public property, and all your bounded objects should implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface for further UI refreshes.